# how to avoid spring data JPA to insert a particular field: @Column(name="cn", insertable = false, updatable=false) did not worked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, data-annotations

I have an entity with a field called cn which means creators name. Creators Name comes from another table.

The field in this entity is creator_id. After reading the documentation I was hopping to be able to work all transaction GET,POST,PUT,DELETE and find_by_id with the same entity, defining those name fields like: @Column(name="cn", insertable = false, updatable=false) private String cn;

But when executing POST I got the next SQL

ERROR 2023-06-23 12:12:44.028 WARN 46523 --- [nio-9087-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 2023-06-23 12:12:44.028 ERROR 46523 --- [nio-9087-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ****Unknown column 'vehicles0_.cn' in 'field list'**** 2023-06-23 12:12:44.035 INFO 46523 --- [nio-9087-exec-8] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener : HHH000327: Error performing load command

So what is insertable = false, updatable=false doing?, and how can I achieve all transactions GET,POST,PUT,DELETE and find_by_id with out having to create a separate entity without all those names (derive fields).

I need This because I have 84 tables and I do not want to duplicate all these entities.

I really appreciated any comment, I have expended more than 10 hours, and documentation about insertable and updatable is exactly what I want it, but it did not work.

I added @Column(name="cn", insertable = false, updatable=false) and I was expecting DATA JPA not to send to the DB the cn field when doing post or put, but per the error it is sending it

Answer (score 0):

If you add @Transient on the entity it will allow JPA to not persist it in the database and hence once the session has been flushed to the database it will not look for the column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).